# Исправление запроса SQL UPDATE

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

Есть такая таблица
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Название рецепта ключевое поле**

Я пытаюсь составить sql запрос, который обновляет значение название рецепта и текст рецепта через 2 текст бокса и нажатие на кнопку редактировать. Но никак не получается

*Я пытаюсь редактировать сразу два поля одно из которых ключевое.*

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=Database777.mdb;";

conn.Open();

string my_querry6 = "update Суп set [Название рецепта]='"+vivodnamerecept.Text+"',[Текст рецепта]='"+vivodtextrecept.Text+"' where[Название рецепта]="+vivodnamerecept.Text+" ";

OleDbCommand cmd6 = new OleDbCommand(my_querry6, conn);
cmd6.ExecuteNonQuery();

conn.Close();
```

И еще вопрос. Я хочу выполнять запрос если выбрано значение в комбобоксе, но не понимаю как построить условие.

```
if(teb6.select ....)
```

Comment: @EvgeniyZ то что запрос идет к аксессу.А wpf и правда можно опустить

Comment: `set [Название рецепта]='"+vivodnamerecept.Text+"` .... `where[Название рецепта]="+vivodnamerecept.Text+"` ?

Comment: @tym32167 Не понял вопроса.. Я редактирую либо название рецепта либо текст рецепта или все сразу.

Comment: Ваш sql запрос выглядит как `установить  название = НОВОЕ_НАЗВАНИЕ для тех строк, где название == НОВОЕ_НАЗВАНИЕ`. Но строк с новым названием у вас в БД ещё нет, потому вот это - `where[Название рецепта]="+vivodnamerecept.Text+"` - по сути вернет пустое множество и ничего не обновит.

Comment: @tym32167 Получается надо каким то образом обратится к имеющимся данным. У меня было  например "Супер суп" я меняю на "Мега суп".Надо как то обратится от старого названия рецепта

Comment: Да, вам надо помнить старое название. Хотя конечно было бы лучше, если бы в таблице был id. изменение ключевого поля обычно очень плохая идея. Пока таблица одна это еще пол беды, но если появятся другие, зависимые от этой таблицы, то замена ключа станет сущим адом

Comment: @Mike у меня в комбобоксе с названием teb6 есть это название рецепта,как его оттуда достать?

Comment: `у меня где то там есть что то, что я не покажу, как мне с этим что то сделать что то`- как, по вашему, мы может узнать, что у вас и где есть? Вы ничего не показали, вам никто ничего и не ответил.